# Does Eto.Forms offer support for .NetCore?

Tags: .net-core, eto

I've seen a bunch of examples/samples of Eto.Forms and WPF.
Does any one know if Eto supports or plans to support .NetCore?

Thanks,
JohnB

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the next version of Eto.Forms (2.5.0) will support .NET Core 3.x for the Eto.Wpf, Eto.WinForms, Eto.Gtk, and Eto.Mac64 platforms giving you the ability to make cross platform applications with native toolkits in .NET Core.

See my answer on GitHub here: https://github.com/picoe/Eto/issues/1559#issuecomment-577918540

Note that Eto.Gtk already supports .NET Core.